# Loudness detection for natural conversation

Tags: audio

I'm working on a project where I want to be able to analyze natural conversation as an audio file and determine the points in the conversation where the speech is louder than normal i.e. be able to classify the points in the audio file that contain louder than normal voice.

I would like to do the same for quieter than normal voice.

Is there any good way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the EBU R-128 method of loudness measuring. Based on an ITU algorithm, it is used to determine loudness for TV which consist mostly of dialogue.

[ITU Docs](https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BS.1770/en)

[EBU R-128 Docs](https://tech.ebu.ch/loudness/#)